# Repeat multiple calculations in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

So yea I want to do something like this

```
aNum = Console.ReadLine();
nNUm= Console.ReadLine();
```

So then I want to repeat aNum*aNum  as long as nNum isnt 0 or less.Is there any way I could do that I tried doing a couple of thing whit while (nNum > 0); but it didnt end well...
Heres the while thing I tried 
    int aNum;
    int nNum;
    int result;

```
aNum = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
nNum = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
result = aNum;

while (nNum > 0)
{
    result = result * aNum;
    nNum = nNum - 1;
}


textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't end well"?

Comment: Well I couldnt run it then i changed the code but it didnt calculate it well...I can add a pic if u need to see what the program actually is.

Comment: why don't you explain why it didn't run (what compilation error message are you getting) and then what results you expect vs. what results you are getting when you say it "didn't calculate it well"

Comment: If you want performing `aNum * aNum` a `nNum` number of times, you must check [Math.Pow method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx) and you don't need the `while()` loop.

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code by something like this.

```
number = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
power = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);

textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Pow(number, power));
```

Comment: Well....if that's what's intended. Entering 2 into both textboxes yields a result of 8....obviously not the same as 2^2.

Comment: @Kazmatron from the OP, I understand that he/she are trying to multiply a number itself a n number of times. This is the definition of Exponentiation, isn't it?

Comment: We're assuming the OP is trying to do an exponent calculation.....but it's never explicitly stated.

Answer (score -1):

Winforms is event based, meaning that you need some kind of trigger for code to execute.

Try adding your code to textBox2_TextChanged event. That way your code will check every time the text changed.

Also surround your Convert calls with a try catch in case the user inputs text that does not convert to int properly.